# Importing the entire Python standard library

Tags: python, import, packaging, py2exe

I need a way to import the entire Python standard library into my program.

While this may seems like a bad idea, I want to do this is so py2exe will package the entire standard library with my program, so my users could import from it in the shell that I give them.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Bonus points: I would prefer that this action will NOT import the packages I have installed in site-packages and which did not come with Python. However, this is not critical.

Comment: What?  You're writing a shell that starts up by pre-importing everything?  What possible use case is there for that?  To save the users typing a dozen characters of "import this"?

Comment: It does not pre-import anything. But for the user to be able to import stuff from the stdlib, I need to import them (or seem like I'm importing them) in my program, so py2exe will know I need them and package them with my executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, I just thought of something: I only need a list of all the modules in stdlib, and then I'll automatically generate a Python script that imports each of them "manually", like this:

```
import re
import math
import time
# ...
```

And then include that with my program.

So all I need now is an easily formatted list of all the modules/packages in stdlib. Now how do I get that?

**UPDATE:**

I got the list like this: I installed Python 2.6 on a virtual machine, then ran in IDLE:

```
import pkgutil
stuff = [thing[1] for thing in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
stuff.sort() # To make it easy to look through
print(stuff)
```

Then copy pasted the output into my IDE, and made a little script to write:

```
if False:
    import re
    import email
    import time
    # ...
```

Into a Python module which I import in my program.

It works! py2exe packs the entire stdlib.

**UPDATE:**

I created a package that does this. I would upload it here but since I don't see any upload button, you can get it off my project folder:

http://github.com/cool-RR/PythonTurtle/tree/master

It's in the folder `src`, the package is called `almostimportstdlib` and it's documented.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/modindex.html

it will take you a little bit of copy & paste and format, but it's a one time task :-)

Comment: I would dynamically generate it personally.  Look at what I said above: you can use the same method to obtain the listing of modules to include and generate a file from that.  It would be better than having to maintain one manually.

Comment: @Ram This is a bit random after all these years, but I just stumbled on your post looking for a solution along the same lines for pyinstaller. I noticed that PythonTurtle also recently switched to pyinstaller and I was wondering how you guys managed to make sure that the entire stdlib is bundled with that. It seems like you dropped `almostimportstdlib` alongside the switch, though from what I can gather pyinstaller also limits the bundled packages to the ones actually imported by the app. If you have any hints on that I'd really appreciate it as my Google-Fu has failed me so far.

Answer (score 1):

I created a zip file from all the Python standard library and then added it to `sys.path` when the program started.

You can have a look at the sources [here](http://svn.berlios.de/svnroot/repos/sconsexe/trunk/) (abandoned project)

Comment: V.good idea.  You should be able to bundle it as a resource using py2exe and add it to the path after the app loads: I know you could do this with PyInstaller at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement in an application that uses [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and solved this by using the [stdlib_list](https://pypi.org/project/stdlib-list/) library and pyinstaller's hidden imports. Example spec file:

```
from stdlib_list import stdlib_list

hidden_imports = []
hidden_imports.extend(stdlib_list("3.9"))

a = Analysis(['myapp.py'],
             pathex=["."],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=hidden_imports,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
...
```

The version must match the python version that you're using in your application.